# How to get params with link_to in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My users have reviews, review may be negative and positive
And now i want show positive and negative reviews for other users
users_controllers.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @reviews = Review.where(for_user_id: @user, negative: false)
      @reviews = @reviews.where(negative: params[:negative]) if params[:negative].present?
      @reviews = @reviews
    end
end
```

and my view
views/users/show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Negative reviews', user_path(negative: true) %>
            <%= link_to 'Positive reviews', user_path(negative: false) %>
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
            <li>
              <div class="user_data">
              <div class="user_review_left">
                <%= link_to (avatar_for review.user, size: "50x50"), review.user %>
              </div>
              <div class="user_review_right">
                <%= link_to review.user.name, review.user %>

                <div class="user_post_name">
                  review for: <%= link_to (truncate review.post.name, length: 50), review.post %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="post_review">
                 <%= review.body %>
              </div>
              <div class="review_date">
                <%= l review.created_at, :format => :my %>
              </div>
            </li>
            <% end %>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

how i can add links for this code?
if user link the  controller return @reviews with params
Thanks

Comment: According to me using UsersController#show for displaying reviews does not sound conventionally correct. UsersController#show should be to display details of User. For displaying reviews of User you should use another member method for this or can use ReviewsCOntroller#index with params to filter records.

Comment: can you write example please =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to 'Negative reviews', user_path(@user, negative: true) %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'Positive reviews', user_path(@user, negative: false) %>
```

and change your `show` method:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @reviews = Review.where(for_user_id: @user, negative: (params[:negative] || false))
end
```

even if I ask myself why you can't do that:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @reviews = @user.reviews.where(for_user_id: @user, negative: (params[:negative] || false))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the user ID **and** the review parameter

> link_to "Reviews", user_path(id: @user.id, negative: true)

Answer (score 0):

As said by coorase appending a parameter to the end of the args will work.

```
<%= link_to 'Negative reviews', user_path(@user, negative: true) %>
```

will create a url like: root/users/:id?negative=true

if you debug inside of the controller action which handles this and evaluate the value of 'params' you will see something like:

```
{"negative"=>"true", "controller"=>"root", "action"=>"index"}
```

this is your params hash and it means that

```
params[:negative] ==> true
```

(I recommend getting the 'pry' gem and inserting 'binding.pry' inside the controller action if you don't have a good debugger you use)

Please be more specific in explaining why this output doesnt work for your  situation and I may be able to help you formulate better parameters